# Preventing the User Interface Layer from Depending on the Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have 3 projects in .NET

- DAL (data access layer)
- UI  (user interface)
- BI ( logic)

DAL call the BI (services)
And The BI Call the DAL (repository)

my problem in my UI project in (global.asax)
- I call my  injector to Register my classes

```
 public Application_Start()
 {
              ......
    container.Register<IService1, Service1Impl>();
    container.Register<IService2, Service2Impl>();
 }
```

But How I can Register my DAL Class without call them in UI Project

Else I have to add my in DAL project in My UI project

Comment: The standard approach is to reference all projects in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)

Comment: And for a solid understanding of DI and application design, do read [this](https://manning.com/seemann2) book.

Answer (score 1):

The `Application_Start` is *not* part of User Interface *layer*. The `Application_Start` is part of the **Composition Root**, which is a layer of its own. You only implicitly decided to place both the **Composition Root** and the User Interface Layer in the same assembly, which is fine.

For more details, about this, see this article: [Understanding the Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

Answer (score 0):

You chose onion-architecture and input-point is UI project. Your UI project must have links to DAL and to BI projects.

If you want to create independent modules in your application, you can choose microservices architecture.